# Calling internal native method directly from another executable

Tags: c#, reflection, external, .net-assembly

For security purposes of my application im trying to call a lower-level function to load my dll.

At first i was using `Assembly.Load` but as i see, it is pretty easy to hook and get the dll bytes.

So what i want to do is to call `nLoadImage` from `RuntimeAssembly` which is the lower-level function to load an assembly.

Here is were the problem comes from, `RuntimeAssembly` is a default library class and is marked as `internal`, the method i need to call, `nLoadImage` is also `internal`.

How could i call that method?

PS. Im using C# with .Net framework.

PS.2. Just to know, is a more low-level way to load an Exe/Dll inside the process? Maybe even by using native functions?

Comment: *"For security purposes of my application"* what exactly are you trying to achieve? You cannot stop a determined person reverse-engineering your code

Comment: 1) Hooking a low-level api is much harder than hooking the most common and simple api to load a dll. 2) "You cannot stop a determined person reverse-engineering your code" sure, but as i said before by doing that ill make it harder.